# java 8 lambda expressions set enabled in JMenuItem ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, lambda, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I have a lambda expression for swing menu.

```
    JMenu color = new JMenu("Color");
    color.add(new JMenuItem("Red")).addActionListener(evt -> panel.setSelectColor(Color.RED));
    color.add(new JMenuItem("Green")).addActionListener(evt -> panel.setSelectColor(Color.green));
    color.add(new JMenuItem("Blue")).addActionListener(evt -> panel.setSelectColor(Color.BLUE));
```

How can i set it enabled or disabled with the lambda function. I know i can do it with 
`color.setEnabled(true);` or `color.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: Which one are you trying to enable/disable?

Comment: The active one. For example i click on "Red". "Green" and "Blue" remains enabled and "Red" is disabled

Comment: Yes for the active menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the lambda expression to a block and loop over all the items in the menue:

```
color.add(new JMenuItem("Red")).addActionListener(evt -> {
   panel.setSelectColor(Color.RED);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < color.getItemCount(); i++){
    color.getItem(i).setEnabled(!evt.getSource().equals(color.getItem(i)));
   }
});
```